How to take integral with respect to an arbitrary variable? Is it possible?
Note: I completely rewrote the question. It will have 2 parts. Part 1 is intended to provide context. Part 2 will be my question.
I am a physics graduate student who is trying to learn cosmology by himself (no lecture). I got mathematically confused while solving a problem. I believe my issue is purely mathematical so I asked it here.
Part 1:
I am expected to find an equation for r with respect to τ. Specifically, the question asks me to find
$r(τ)=R\sqrt{E^2 - 1}\sinh(τ/R)$
The question only provides me with the following spacetime metric and nothing else.
$ds^2=-(1-\frac{r^2}{R^2}) dt^2 + (1-\frac{r^2}{R^2})^{-1} dr^2 +r^2 (dθ^2+\sin^2(θ) dφ^2 )$
Lagrangian was not given but I found it as (and also confirmed that it is true)
$\mathcal{L}= (1-\frac{r^2}{R^2}) \dot{t}^2 - (1-\frac{r^2}{R^2})^{-1} \dot{r}^2 - r^2 (\dot{θ}^2+\sin^2(θ) \dot{φ}^2 )\equiv -g_{μν}\dot{x}^μ \dot{x}^ν$
Using an equation known as Euler-Lagrange I found a set of equations of motion. As physicists, we use this terminology to refer to a set of acceleration equations ie. second derivatives of displacements (θ,φ,r,t in this case). Only 2 of these seem relevant in my problem.
$\ddot{r} = \frac{-r \dot{r}^2}{R^2 -r^2} + (1- \frac{r^2}{R^2}) [\dot{θ}^2 + \frac{L^2}{r^4 \sin^2(θ)} + \frac{E^2}{R^2 - r^2} (1- \frac{r^2}{R^2})^{-1}]$
$\ddot{θ}=\frac{\cos(θ)}{\sin^3(θ)} \frac{L^2}{r^4} - \frac{2\dot{θ}\dot{r}}{r}$
where $E=\dot{t} (1-\frac{r^2}{R^2})=constant$ , $L= r^2 \sin^2(θ) \dot{φ}=constant$ and R=constant.
Traditionally, equations of motion is formulated as derivatives with respect to t. But this is not the case in my equations. They are formulated with respect to some arbitrary λ. Whatever that λ may be…
Dot derivatives are with respect to that arbitrary lambda. For example,
$\ddot{θ}=\frac{d^2θ}{dλ^2}$
Equations I gave for $\ddot{r}$ and $\ddot{θ}$ seems to be coupled due to $\dot{θ}$ in $\ddot{r}$ so I naturally thought that I need to find $\dot{θ}$ and plug it in.
But there is an issue…
Part 2:
$\dot{θ} = \int \ddot{θ} dλ=\int (\frac{\cos(θ)}{\sin^3(θ)} \frac{L^2}{r^4} - \frac{2\dot{θ}\dot{r}}{r})dλ$
How do I take an integral with respect to an arbitrary variable? If my task is impossible, can you please give some hints as to deal with coupled equations of this kind?
λ can be changed as τ in the end since question specifically asks for r(τ). However, switching to τ at this stage is not useful because we have no idea as to what θ(τ) is. It is simply not given.
I will also quote the beginning of the question below:
“The particle is released with a small radial velocity near r=0. Show that its trajectory is… (shows r(τ))”
The question may suggest an approximation but it feels a bit too early to utilize assumptions or approximations.
My attempt at solving $\dot{θ}=\int \ddot{θ} dλ$ :
$\dot{θ} = \int (\frac{\cos(θ)}{\sin^3(θ)} \frac{L^2}{r^4} - \frac{2\dot{θ}\dot{r}}{r})dλ = I_1 - I_2$
$I_1= \int \frac{\cos(θ)}{\sin^3(θ)} \frac{L^2}{r^4} dλ = \int u dv= \frac{\cos(θ)}{\sin^3(θ)} \int \frac{L^2}{r^4} dλ - \int (\int \frac{L^2}{r^4} dλ) (\frac{-1}{\sin^2(θ)}-\frac{3\cos^2(θ)}{\sin^4(θ)})dθ$
I feel like $I_1$ is 0 (assuming r does not depend on θ)? But this is just a feeling.
$I_2=\int \frac{2\dot{θ}\dot{r}}{r} dλ$
$I_2$ boogles my mind a bit more. I wrote (using integration by parts)
$I_2=2[\dot{θ} \ln(r) - \int \ln(r) \ddot{θ} dλ]$

It's a little unclear what you mean by $\lambda$ being an arbitrary variable. When we take derivatives, or integrals, it must be with respect to some particular quantity or quantities.

Since really it is just $\tau$ its not arbitrary and you have to know how r and $\Theta$  depend on $\tau$. No other possibility.

λ is arbitrary but… you are right about we can treat it as τ since the answer expects a result in terms of τ. Unfortunately we don’t know how r and θ depend on τ.

Is it possible that you’re being asked to find the equations of motion of radial free fall into Schwarzchild? This causes $L,\dot\varphi,\dot\theta$ to vanish, simplifying the equations of motion considerably.

@kieransquared It doesn’t explicitly state “radial free” but yeah that assumption simplifies the equations greatly. I have also remembered that if Lagrangian does not depend on λ explicitly, it would make the lagrangian a constant (=1 for particles with mass). I am also considering about how to utilize this info about lagrangian.
